# Default omit case

Tags: c#, switch-statement

Using Switch case Some values are inserted to dropdwnlist.The dropdown values are different When different users are loged.In Default case I can't Accept a common value in this case.So I Omit the default case.But I don't know it cause a future problem.If any one can help me Some suggestion to  over come this situation.
The code is given Bellow

```
private void loadUserGroup()
{
    CUsers objCUsers = new CUsers();
    ddlUserGroup.Items.Clear();
    // ddlUserGroup.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", "0"));
    ddlUserGroup.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Admin", "2"));
    string suserid = User.Identity.Name;
    int iUserID = Convert.ToInt32(suserid.ToString());
    long iUserGroup = objCUsers.SelectUserGroup(iUserID);
    switch (iUserGroup)
    {
        case 2:
            ddlUserGroup.Visible = false;
            lblUserGroup.Visible = false;
           break;
        case 3:
            ddlUserGroup.Visible = true;
            lblUserGroup.Visible = true;
            ddlUserGroup.Items.Clear();
            ddlUserGroup.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Dealer", "5"));
            ddlUserGroup.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("CompanyAdmin", "4"));//Similar To Admin
           break;
        case 4:
            ddlUserGroup.Items.Clear();
            ddlUserGroup.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("CompanyAdmin", "4"));
           break;
        case 5:
            ddlUserGroup.Items.Clear();
            ddlUserGroup.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Client", "6"));
           break;
    }

}
```

Comment: What problem do you think you will have?

Comment: Yeah. Given that the syntax says and a compiler will confirm athat you do not need a default case the question makes no sense - there is non asked either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your issue is that a fitting default option simply does not exist in your situation, is that right? Then I guess you have two options:

Either treat it like an error, and then handle it in an outer scope somehow:

```
case default:
    throw new Exception("No valid user!");
    break;
```

...otherwise, you could just provide an empty drop-down (or ensure that the drop-down is empty by clearing it):

```
case default:
    ddlUserGroup.Items.Clear();
    // Nothing to add here!
    break;
```

The latter here, is pretty much the same as not including a `default` at all, except that you explicitly ensure that it is empty here. You could probably just do that before the whole Switch-case though, if you are going to clear it in each case anyway.

Answer (score 0):

[switch C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx)

```
If there is no default section, no action is taken and control is transferred
outside the switch statement.
```

---

try this

```
default:
 ddlUserGroup.Items.Clear();
break
```

Answer (score 0):

The missing default branch in the switch statement for itself should not be a problem. Especially as your question is related to user rights, it is better to be more specific than to have unwanted effects to due a default branch that is executed when it should not. An alternative would be to explicitly throw an exception in the default branch in order to signal an unexpected value.

However, switch statements often are problematic from a maintainability point of view. Now, this switch statement might be the only one that handles different user rights. As your application grows there will be several spots that need to handle user rights differently. If you need to add a user right, you'd have to change all of these spots - and you might miss the one or the other.

Therefore, a polymorphic approach is better suited in this situation. In your sample, instead of retrieving the user group from `CUsers`, you could add a property to `CUsers` that returns the values for the ComboBox. The property returns an `IEnumerable<UserGroup>` or `IReadOnlyCollection<UserGroup>` where `UserGroup` is a new class with at least a property `Name` and`Id`. Your code to use this property would not contain a switch statement anymore:

```
private void loadUserGroup()
{
    CUsers objCUsers = new CUsers();
    ddlUserGroup.Items.Clear();
    // ddlUserGroup.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", "0"));
    ddlUserGroup.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Admin", "2"));
    string suserid = User.Identity.Name;
    int iUserID = Convert.ToInt32(suserid.ToString());
    // Get user groups using the new property
    var userGroups = objCUsers.UserGroups;
    lblUserGroup.Visible = userGroups.Any();
    ddlUserGroup.Visible = lblUserGroup.Visible;
    ddlUserGroup.Items.Clear();
    foreach(var userGroup in userGroups)
       ddlUserGroup.Items.Add(new ListItem(userGroup.Name, userGroup.Id));
}
```

As you see, your code is much shorter. All subsequent changes to the user groups will be done in `CUsers`. If you move all the user rights related methods to `CUsers` like this, you will only have to change `CUsers` instead of running over a lot of code and changing many spots. Forgetting a spot is less likely this way.